# Get Intune Compliance policy settings using Graph API

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

To get the Compliance Policy Settings in Intune, we need to use the below api ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-deviceintent-devicemanagementsettingdefinition-list?view=graph-rest-beta)):

Request URL: **https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/settings**

Request Method: **GET**

I can run the api and get the details using Postman, however im struggling to get the API running using Microsoft Graph (Beta) in Java.

Example : Im using the below code snipped for fetching all the compliance policies using microsoft graph beta api:

```
List<DeviceCompliancePolicy> allDeviceCompliancePolicies = new ArrayList<DeviceCompliancePolicy>();
            DeviceCompliancePolicyCollectionPage deviceCompliancePolicyCollectionPage = this.graphClient
                    .getGraphServiceClient().deviceManagement().deviceCompliancePolicies().buildRequest()
                    .expand("assignments,scheduledActionsForRule($expand=scheduledActionConfigurations)").get();

            while (deviceCompliancePolicyCollectionPage != null) {
                final List<DeviceCompliancePolicy> deviceCompliancePolicies = deviceCompliancePolicyCollectionPage
                        .getCurrentPage();
                allDeviceCompliancePolicies.addAll(deviceCompliancePolicies);
                final DeviceCompliancePolicyCollectionRequestBuilder nextPage = deviceCompliancePolicyCollectionPage
                        .getNextPage();
                if (nextPage == null) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    deviceCompliancePolicyCollectionPage = nextPage.buildRequest().get();
                }
            }
```

From the javadoc its clear the settings are seen in **DeviceManagementSettings** class, however im unable to get an instance of that class using graph api.

Any help to resolve the above is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code snippet for fetch Compliance policy settings from Intune.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

DeviceManagementSettings deviceManagementSettings = graphClient.customRequest("/deviceManagement/settings", DeviceManagementSettings.class)
    .buildRequest()
    .get();
```

The easiest way to find the code snippet for any Graph api is by using [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), run the api and check **Code snippets**